# Creating a guessing game in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am brand new to coding with C++ and taking my first course.  This is supposed to be a very simple program, the objective is for the program to read a number from the input stream and does not display it.  Next, ask the user to try to guess the number; give them up to three guesses.  The various outputs should show when the user never guesses correctly, guesses correctly on the first guess, second guess, and third guess. The outputs should read something like:

```
I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10. 
Can you guess it within 3 guesses? 
Enter guess #1: 6 
Enter guess #2: 7 
Enter guess #3: 8 
You lose! The number was 5

I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10. 
Can you guess it within 3 guesses? 
Enter guess #1: 66 
Please try again Enter guess #1: 67 
Please try again Enter guess #1: 68 
Please try again Enter guess #1: 6 
Enter guess #2: 7 Enter guess #3: 8 
You lose! The number was 5
```

The problem that I am having is if the guess is either correct or wrong it will continuously print out You lose! The number was ...  or if the guess is correct it does the something.  Also, if the guess it outside of 1 and 10 it will continuously print out Please try again as well as the you lose statement.  Here is the code I have so far, I only created code for the first guess until it performs correctly.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main () {
  int guess;
  int guess2;
  int guess3;
  int ran;
  srand(time(0));

  cout << "I am thinking of a number bewteen 1 and 10." << endl;
  cout << "Can you guess it within 3 guesses?" << endl;

  cin >> guess;
  cin >> guess2;
  cin >> guess3;

  ran = ((rand() % 9) + 1);

  cout << ran << endl; //remove***********

  cout << "Guess #1: " << guess << endl;

   while(guess < 1 || guess > 10) { 
        cout << "Please try again" << endl;

           }  
     while(guess != ran) {
        cout << "You lose!  The number was " << ran << endl;
     }

     while(guess == ran) {
        cout << "You win!  The number was " << ran << endl;

     }

  return 0;
   }
```

Comment: `while(guess != ran)` will continue until `guess == ran`.  There is nothing in the body of the loop that changes either `guess` or `ran`.  This is what we call an infinite loop.  You probably want `if` instead of `while`.

Comment: thanks, I changed to if statements and it works better, however how can I get to stop if it either guesses correctly on the first guess, then stops on second for correct guess, and if it is outside 1 and 10 how to start over with guess 1?

Answer (score 0):

Because neither `guess` nor `ran` changes in the loop that prints `"You lose!"`, the loop will never terminate.  It isn't clear to me why this is a loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for loop instead of having 3 guess variables. also, use if instead of while.
    int main () {

```
int guess, ran, i;

srand(time(0));

cout << "I am thinking of a number bewteen 1 and 10." << endl;
cout << "Can you guess it within 3 guesses?" << endl;

ran = ((rand() % 9) + 1);

cout << ran << endl; //remove***********

for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
{
 cin >> guess;
 cout << "Guess #1: " << guess << endl;

if(guess < 1 || guess > 10) 
    cout << "Please try again" << endl;

if(guess == ran) 
    break;

}

if(guess != ran)
    cout << "you lose!";
if(guess == ran)
cout << "you win!";

return 0;
}
```